# render a view from another controller, yii

Tags: yii, yii1.x

The controller:

```
controllers
|-FooController.php
|-BarController.php
```

The views:

```
view
|-foo|
|    |-index.php
|    |-error.php
|
|-bar|
     |-index.php
```

How to render the error.php view with an action of the bar controller?
I have tried:

```
$this->render('foo/error');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: try `$this->render('/foo/error')`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

try this

```
$this->render('//foo/error');
```

Comment: How this is handled in Yii2 is documented here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#named-views

Comment: I confirm this works in Yii2, in case you don't want to read the doc

Answer (score 2):

If you don't **echo it**, you will get a blank page.
The correct way is

```
<?=
   $this->render('//foo/error');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
     echo $this->render('//foo/error');
?>
```

This also works for Yii2

Comment: In Yii2 it's also working with a single `/` at the beginning, like: `<?= $this->render('/foo/error') ?>`