# Yii2 call action from another module

Tags: yii

i have a module called '**elite**' which render articles and another module called '**inet**'.

**Inet->controllerX** need to get the HTML only from an article(**elite->article->actionView**).

so my question is:

should i call **elite->article->actionView** from another module or use components and inheritance and how?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [render a view from another controller, yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699309/render-a-view-from-another-controller-yii)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303876/yii2-render-module-view-from-main-application This will help you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [widgets](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-widgets). From the maintainability point of view I don't think using view templates across modules is good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily render a view in any module, just need view path.

```
return $this->render('@app/modules/elite/views/name_controller/name_view');
```

You must replace the name of the controller and the name of the view.

Comment: yes i tried this before but i was missing the @app/

Thank you!